# overnight index swaps OIS

Tags: interest-rate, finance, federal-reserve

I'm writing a paper where I am using expected federal funds rates at different horizons and wanted to use the OIS as a proxy for what the market expects the FFR to be post FOMC-meetings. However, I can't seem to find the data anywhere. Does anyone know where I can get these and if not, what else I can use as proxies about market expectations about the FFR?

Comment: See https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33463/is-there-any-public-data-to-get-ois-for-differal-time-1d-1w-1m-10y

Comment: Probably not the correct stack exchange (see Henry’s link), but the only alternative is Fed Fund Futures. Since they are monthly averages, can’t pinpoint exact dates.